# how to parse the array value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following array response:

```
[0] => Array ([taxname] => Service tax @ 14% [taxamount] => 140000) 
[1] => Array ([taxname] => swachh bharat cess @ 0.5% [taxamount] => 5000) [rowcount] => 2)
```

I am using the following code for display the result in view:

```
<?php   

    for($i=0;$i<$rowcount;$i++)
    {
        echo $i['taxName'];
    }

?>
```

But nothing is displayed.

Comment: add your complete code. Model controller and view

Comment: Think about what exactly the value `$i` is in each iteration. Otherwise place `print_r($i);` inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
[0] => Array ( [taxname] => Service tax @ 14% [taxamount] => 140000 ) [1] => Array ( [taxname] => swachh bharat cess @ 0.5% [taxamount] => 5000 ) [rowcount] => 2 )

consider an $array = array('taxname'=>'Service tax @ 14% ');

//if you are sending from the controller:

$data['myarray'] = $array;

$this->load->view('viewfile',$data);


In the View:

foreach($myarray as $key=>$value){
  echo $value;
}
echo $myarray['taxname'];
```

Comment: @user3833740 if this answer works you should accept the answer.